# preg_replace - only letters and replace spaces for plus character

Tags: php, regex, replace

I would like to accept in string **PHP** only letters and change all spaces for plus (+) character. Further I would like to accept only one plus next to each other. So this string:
`$string = 'ex,a-mpl*e   s++tri  ng';`
sholud replace for:
`$string = 'example+s+tri+ng';`

I tried like that:
`#[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\]#`
but that isn't helpful for me.

Can you help me? :)

EDIT:

aahh, and I would like to also accept only strings where string's lenth is 3 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if something like this could be a good starting point:

```
$string = 'ex,a-mpl*e s++tri ng';

$pattern = array(
    '/([^a-zA-Z\+\s])/',
    '/(\+|\s)+/'
);  

$replacement = array('', '+');

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, (strlen($string) > 3) ? $string : false);

var_dump($result); //<- return an empty string if the length is < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Just letters and digits

You got your regex already, just use it

```
$str = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\]#', '', $str);
```

#### Replace Spaces, strip multiple ones

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $str);
```

#### How to solve such things

I don't want to be rude but the code I pasted, is just a slightly change of Example #4 from here https://www.php.net/en/preg_replace

So please questions like this are very common and php.net really does a good job with putting examples together. So try to search there first!